# Can interfaces work with Stream API in java 8?

Tags: java-8

My friend give me a challenge. The challenge is related to the following interface. I will write the questions in the challenge and my answer to those below.

```
interface Student{
    int getAge();
    /**
     *
     * @return if gender is male will return 1, else 0
     */
    int getGender();

    String getName();
}
```

**Question 1**- Is there any better return type to the **getGender()** method rather than **int**? if exists explain why is it better than int?

**My answer**-  boolean is good for it. because int takes 4 bytes space(32 bits) but boolean takes only I bit so boolean will save the space. we can assume male is true and female as false.

**Question 2** -Think if you have a list of Students named **studentList**. So then how you filter the students who are less than 18 years old?

**My answer** -Actually **Student** is an interface, not a class. so then we cannot filter the age without an age property. If this **Student** was a class and **studentList** was a collection of Student class instances, we can use the stream API to filter the student ages. So this filtering task cannot do because there is no object stream. So the question is not meaningful.

Those are the questions and answers. What about my answers? are they wrong or right? if you can give me an explanation about this it would be very help to me.

Comment: (1) An `enum` would probably be best. (2) Yes, `Student` is an interface but it has a `#getAge()` method, meaning _every implementation_ will have that method as well—you can filter based on the result of calling that method.

Comment: 1- boolean is not good since you ignore other genders. the enum value is better since it more readable. 2- have you tried for it?

Comment: The Stream API can work with interfaces just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. "Is there any better return type to the getGender() method rather than int? if exists explain why is it better than int?"

You chose `boolean`. That only gives you two options which, in the modern world, may not be acceptable. At the very least you should have "male", "female", and "other". You also mention using `boolean` is a good choice because it saves space. In today's age you most likely don't need to worry about that for something so simple. Using `boolean` is also not particularly readable, which can often be the more important factor when writing code. With this in mind, using an `enum` would probably be best:

```java
public enum Gender {
  MALE,
  FEMALE,
  OTHER
}
```

Of course, this only works if all genders are known at compile-time. If your users can define genders at runtime then you'll need to use something different. The simplest option would be `String`, but you may want to use a dedicated class. The important part is that the new genders can be persisted and retrieved as needed.

#### 2. "Think if you have a list of Students named studentList. So then how you filter the students who are less than 18 years old?"

Your answer mentions you can't filter `Student` because it's an interface. It doesn't matter that `Student` is an interface because if you have an instance of `Student` then the *implementation* will be a "real object". The interface defines a `getAge()` method which means every concrete implementation of `Student` will have to implement that method. This is what interfaces are for—defining contracts. So if you have a list of `Student` you can easily filter by age:

```java
List<Student> studentList = ...; // get list from somewhere
List<Student> minors =
    studentList.stream().filter(stu -> stu.getAge() < 18).collect(Collectors.toList());
```